# Efficiently updating ARSCNFaceGeometry from a set of blend shapes

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am using `ARSCNFaceGeometry` and need to update the face model's blend shapes as part of my game loop. My current solution is to call [`ARSCNFaceGeometry.update`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnfacegeometry/2928196-update) with a new `ARFaceGeometry`:

```swift
class Face {
    let geometry: ARSCNFaceGeometry
    
    init(device: MTLDevice) {
        guard let geometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device, fillMesh: true) else {
            fatalError("Could not create ARSCNFaceGeometry")
        }
        self.geometry = geometry
    }
    
    func update(blendShapes: [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation: NSNumber]) {
        let faceGeometry = ARFaceGeometry(blendShapes: blendShapes)!
        geometry.update(from: faceGeometry)
    }
}
```

However this is not suitable for realtime usage since the `ARFaceGeometry` line alone takes around 0.01 seconds (just for reference, at 60fps we have a total frame budget of 0.0166 seconds).

After a few hundred updates or so, we seem to run to some sort of bug that takes the entire game loop to 10-20fps. Here's a 6 second sample from the profiler that sees `ARFaceGeometry` taking 2.3 seconds!:

[image: ARFaceGeometry taking 2.3 seconds in a 6 second sample]

Is there a more efficient way to update an existing `ARSCNFaceGeometry` from a set of blend shapes?

With custom 3D models for example, I can just update the blend shape values on [`SCNNode.morpher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408022-morpher). Is there an equivalent for `ARSCNFaceGeometry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not track down the ARFaceGeometry performance problems. To workaround this, I instead decided to build my own model from `ARFaceGeometry`.

First I generated a model file from `ARFaceGeometry`. This file includes the base geometry as well as the geometry when each individual blend shape is applied:

```swift
let LIST_OF_BLEND_SHAPES: [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation] = [
    .eyeBlinkLeft,
    .eyeLookDownLeft,
    // ... fill in rest
]

func printFaceModelJson() {
    // Get the geometry without any blend shapes applied 
    let base = ARFaceGeometry(blendShapes: [:])!
    
    // First print out a single copy of the indices.
    // These are shared between the models
    let indexList = base.triangleIndices.map({ "\($0)" }).joined(separator: ",")
    print("indexList: [\(indexList)]")
    
    // Then print the starting geometry (i.e. no blend shapes applied)
    printFaceNodeJson(blendShape: nil)
    
    // And print the model with each blend shape applied
    for blend in LIST_OF_BLEND_SHAPES {
        printFaceNodeJson(blendShape: blend)
    }
}

func printFaceNodeJson(
    blendShape: ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation?
) {
    let geometry = ARFaceGeometry(blendShapes: blendShape != nil ? [blendShape!: 1.0] : [:])!
    
    let verticies = geometry.vertices.flatMap({ v in [v[0], v[1], v[2]] })
    let vertexList = verticies.map({ "\($0)" }).joined(separator: ",")
    print("{ \"blendShape\": \(blendShape != nil ?  "\"" + blendShape!.rawValue + "\"" : "null"), \"verticies\": [\(vertexList)] }")
}
```

I ran this code offline to generate the model file (quickly converting the output by hand to proper json). You could also use a proper 3D model file format, which would likely result in a smaller model file.

Then for my app, I reconstruct the model from the json model file:

```swift
class ARMaskFaceModel {
    
    let node: SCNNode
    
    init() {
        let data = loadMaskJsonDataFromFile() // implement this!
        
        let elements = [SCNGeometryElement(indices: data.indicies, primitiveType: .triangles)]
        
        // Create the base geometry
        let baseGeometryData = data.blends[0]
        let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [
            SCNGeometrySource(vertices: baseGeometryData.verticies)
        ], elements: elements)
        
        node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        
        // Then load each of the blend shape geometries into a morpher
        let morpher = SCNMorpher()
        morpher.targets = data.blends.dropFirst().map({ x in
            SCNGeometry(sources: [
                SCNGeometrySource(vertices: x.verticies)
            ], elements: elements)
        })
        node.morpher = morpher
    }

    /// Apply blend shapes to the model
    func update(blendShapes: [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation : NSNumber]) {
        var i = 0
        for blendShape in LIST_OF_BLEND_SHAPES {
            if i > node.morpher?.targets.count ?? 0 {
                return
            }
            node.morpher?.setWeight(CGFloat(truncating: blendShapes[blendShape] ?? 0.0), forTargetAt: i)
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Not ideal, but it works ok and performs much better, even without any optimization. We're pretty consistently at 60fps now. Plus it works on older phones too! (although `printFaceModelJson` must be run on a phone that supports realtime face tracking)

Answer (score 0):

Apple Developer Documentation says:

> To update a SceneKit model of a face actively tracked in an AR session, call this method in your ARSCNViewDelegate object’s `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)` callback, passing the geometry property from the ARFaceAnchor object that callback provides.

## First code version

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
              nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        let faceGeo = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeo)
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
        return node
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
              didUpdate node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
           let faceGeo = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry {

            if faceAnchor.lookAtPoint.x >=  0 {
                faceGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            } else {
                faceGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
            }

            faceGeo.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
            self.facialExrpession(anchor: faceAnchor)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label.text = self.textBoard
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
extension ViewController {

    func facialExrpession(anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {

        self.textBoard = "PLEASE SMILE!"
        let smileLeft = anchor.blendShapes[.mouthSmileLeft]
        let smileRight = anchor.blendShapes[.mouthSmileRight]

        if ((smileLeft?.decimalValue ?? 0.0) + 
            (smileRight?.decimalValue ?? 0.0)) > 0.5 {
            self.textBoard += "You are smiling"
        }
    }
}
```

## Second code version

```
import ARKit
import Metal

class BlendShapes: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    typealias BlendShapeDict = [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation: NSNumber]
    var collectBlendShapes: ((BlendShapeDict) -> Void)?

    let geometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!, 
                                   fillMesh: true)
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
              didUpdate node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let facialAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
        let blendShapes: (Any)? = collectBlendShapes?(facialAnchor.blendShapes)
        
        geometry!.update(from: blendShapes as! ARFaceGeometry)
    }
}
```

> Alternatively, you can create, configure, and visualize face models independent of an AR session by creating face geometry objects using the ARFaceGeometry init(blendShapes:) initializer and passing them to this method.

Comment: I'm trying to play back an animation from a set of recorded blend shape values so I can't use a `ARFaceAnchor` (although I can confirm that updating from `ARFaceAnchor` doesn't cause this performance problem). Let me try out force casting a set of blend shapes  to `ARFaceGeometry` though

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `collectBlendShapes` isn't defined so the value of `blend_shapes` is  always `nil` which then causes a crash

Comment: Fill it with your collection of blendShapes. And you should use optional binding (`guard let` statement, for example) to extract non-optional collection.

Comment: Can you update your answer to show how that'd work?

Comment: The cast on `blendShapes as! ARFaceGeometry` seems to be causing issues for me. The blend shapes are a `[ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation: NSNumber]` and I see a runtime crash if I force cast that to a  `ARFaceGeometry`